# ColdFusion Execution Time Accuracy

Tags: coldfusion

I found a [very old thread](http://mail-archive.com/cfcdev@cfczone.org/msg09731.html) from 2004 that reported the fact that the execution times listed in ColdFusion debugging output are only accurate to the 16ms. Meaning, that when you turn debugging output on and look at execution times, you're seeing an estimate to the closest multiple of 16ms. I can see this today with ACF10. When refreshing a page, most times bounce between multiples of 15-16ms.

**Here are the questions:**

1. Starting at the bottom, when ColdFusion reports 0ms or 16ms, does
   that always mean somewhere between 0 and 16, but not over 16ms?
2. When coldfusion reports 32 ms, does this mean somewhere between
   17 and 32?
3. ColdFusion lists everything separately by default rather than as
   an execution tree where callers include many functions. When
   determining the execution cost higher up on the tree, is it summing
   the "innaccurate" times of the children, or is this a realistic cost
   of the actual time all the child processes took to execute?
4. Can we use cftimers or getTickCount() to actually get accurate
   times, or are these also estimates?
5. Sometimes, you'll see that 3 functions took 4ms each for a total of 12ms or even a single call taking 7ms. Why does it sometimes seem "accurate?"

**I will now provide some guesses, but I'd like some community support!**

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. ColdFusion will track report accurate to the 16ms the total time that process took rather than summing the child processes.
4. cftimers and getTickCount() are more accurate.
5. I have no idea?

Comment: I just looked at the page on my other tab.  The total time was 125.  Other times were 78 for an included template and 63 for a query.  None of these are multiples of 15 or 16.  I'm using version 9.

Comment: I do find queries tend to be accurate. Find a page that might have about 200 non-query related methods being called. You'll see the pattern emerge.

Comment: I thought timing accuracy was a problem with browser's JS engines, not CF.  Where is the thread you mentioned?

Comment: Good ol' CFCdev: http://www.mail-archive.com/cfcdev@cfczone.org/msg09731.html

Comment: Henry, You are saying that the debugging output execution times are calculated in JavaScript?

Comment: @J.T. no, I was saying I haven't heard of this. I've only heard it in the JS land.

Comment: @Henry I believe I found the answer and answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, you either have System.currentTimeMillis() or System.nanoTime().

I assume getTickCount() merely returns System.currentTimeMillis(). It's also used by ColdFusion to report debugging output execution times. You can find on numerous StackOverflow questions  complaining about the inaccuracy of System.currentTimeMillis() because it is reporting from the operating system. On Windows, the accuracy can vary quite a bit, up to 50ms some say. It doesn't take leap ticks into account or anything. However, it is fast. Queries seem to report either something from the JDBC driver, the SQL engine, or another method as they are usually accurate.

As an alternative, if you really want increased accuracy, you can use this:

`currentTime = CreateObject("java", "java.lang.System").nanoTime()`

That is less performant than currentTimeMillis(), but it is precise down to nanoseconds. You can divide by 1000 to get to microseconds. You'll want to wrap in precisionEvaluate() if you are trying to convert to milliseconds by dividing by 1000000.

Please note that nanoTime() is not accurate to the nanosecond, is just precise to the nanosecond. It's accuracy is just a matter of being an improvement over currentTimeMillis().

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment then an answer but i can't comment yet.

In my experience the minimum execution time for a query is 0 ms or 16 ms. It is never 8ms or 9ms. For fun you can try this:

```
<cfset s = gettickcount()>
<cfset sleep(5)>
<cfset e = gettickcount() -s>
<Cfoutput>#e#</cfoutput>
```

I tried it with different values it seems the expected output and the actual output always differ in the range from 0ms to 16ms no matter what value is used. It seems that coldfusion (java) is accurate with a margin of about 16 ms.

Comment: I think I found the answer as noted above. Thanks for your help.